# How to find the coordinates of the vertices of an equilateral triangle inscribed in a given circle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, solution-verification, triangles, analytic-geometry

Let $C = (a, b)$ be any given point in the plane, and let $r$ be any given positive real number. Then how to find the coordinates of the vertices of an equilateral triangle inscribed in the circle
$$
\left\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2 \right\}?
$$

My Attempt:

> Let $P$, $Q$, $R$ be the vertices one such  equilateral triangle. Then we have
> $$
> \triangle PCQ \cong \triangle QCR \cong \triangle RCP.
> $$
> So we have
> $$
> \angle PCQ \cong \angle QCR \cong \angle RCP,
> $$
> which implies that
> $$
> m \angle PCQ = m \angle QCR = m \angle RCP = \frac{\pi}{3}. 
> $$
> Moreover, we also have
> $$
> \vec{OP} = \vec{OC} + \vec{CP}.
> $$
> If $\alpha$ is the angle that $\vec{CP}$ makes with the positive $x$-axis, where $0 \leq \alpha < 2 \pi$, then we have
> $$
> \vec{OP} = (a + r \cos \alpha ) \hat{i} + ( b + r \sin \alpha ) \hat{j}. 
> $$
> Thus we have
> $$
> P =  \big( a + r \cos \alpha, b + r \sin \alpha \big). 
> $$
> Since the angle between the vectors $\vec{CP}$ and $\vec{CQ}$ and the angle between $\vec{CQ}$ and $\vec{CR}$ is $\frac{\pi}{3}$, we have
> $$
> \vec{OQ} = \vec{OC} + \vec{CQ} = \left( a + r \cos \left( \alpha + \frac{\pi}{3} \right) \right) \hat{i} +  \left( b + r \sin \left( \alpha + \frac{\pi}{3} \right) \right) \hat{j},
> $$
> and therefore we have
> $$
> Q = \left( a + r \cos \left( \alpha + \frac{\pi}{3} \right) \, , \, b + r \sin \left( \alpha + \frac{\pi}{3} \right)  \right). 
> $$
> Similarly, we have
> $$
> R = \left( a + r \cos \left( \alpha + \frac{2\pi}{3} \right) \, , \, b + r \sin \left( \alpha + \frac{2 \pi }{3} \right)  \right). 
> $$

Is my solution correct and clear enough? Or, are there any problems?

Comment: You introduce a Point 0 with no comment? The angle between CP and CQ is 2pi/3 not pi/3 , pi/3 is the angle beween PQ and PR.

Comment: If 
$$
P=(a+r\cos\alpha,b+r\sin\alpha),
$$
then
$$
Q=\left(a+r\cos\left(\alpha+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right),b+r\sin\left(\alpha+\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\right),
$$
$$
R=\left(a+r\cos\left(\alpha+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right),b+r\sin\left(\alpha+\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)\right).
$$
No computation is needed to establish this.